# Use of Sprintf function in C

Tags: c, string, printf

How to include another string in sprintf function. See the example -\

```
char data[6] = {0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20};
char buff[50];

sprintf(buff, "I want to add this string - < ? >",data) ;
```

1. My question is whether this is valid ?
2. If yes then what is the correct access specifier i should add. %s is not working.

I want the my `buff` would be like - I want to add this string - 202020202020

Please Suggest.

Comment: You need a format string. Like with printf. You know what a format string is, don't you?

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i, len = 0;
    char data[6] = {0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20};
    char buff[50];

    for(i=0;i<sizeof(data);++i){
        len += sprintf(buff + len, "%02x", (unsigned char)data[i]);
    }
    printf("%s\n", buff);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can even do a bufferoverflow check with this solution "if (len+3 > sizeof(buff)) do something; else len += ...

Comment: @PeterMiehle It can be calculated in advance by the `2*sizeof(data)+1` is desired buffer size for output.

Answer (score 4):

The `sprintf` used to convert any data into String.

Your data is hexadecimal data. so use `%x` formate specifier.

Try this code

```
sprintf(buff,"%x%x%x%x%x%x",data[0],data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4],data[5]);
printf("%s\n",buff);
```

It will give the result as `202020202020`.

Comment: Suppose my string is of 100 charcters then ??

Comment: characters or Intergers??

Comment: what data you are going to convert as a string, you need to use format specifier of that data. if you want convert integers means use %d format specifier.

Comment: Does it matter ?? 0x20 is also a character - (space). So whatever it is, I just want to know if my string is large, then applying your above suggestion is cumbersome.

Comment: I know how to use sprintf. The suggestion U gave above na, that will work fine. String data[] only contains 6 characters. Just i need a little more help that if my string is more than 50 or 100 then how to include it to buff[]. Thanks.

Comment: The space is in your data declaration does not a matter. but space in sprintf matters. sprintf(buff,"%x %x %x %x %x %x",data[0],data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4],data[5]); it gives the result as 20 20 20 20 20 20

Comment: for large strings you need to go with some other method.

Comment: @Aseem how fit data in less size buffer?..you should have enough size of buffer to hold data.

Answer (score 0):

Sprintf is used to print to a string. Its similar to printf with a difference that the output is to the string and not to the console.